# Android OKHttp and Retrofit return 304 error

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm develop an android application using OKHttp and Retrofit to send request to skyscanner API.

But sometime I got 304 response and this response have no body content. So I can't parse the body content to my object and that's why my listview show nothing.

Can anyone help me to avoid 304 error.

Comment: what server are you running on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

304 is not an error. 304 refers to a redirect, and is the responsibility of the client to handle it.

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E304.html

You are most likely doing a GET request on a document that has not changed, and you should depend on your cache to handle that for you.